# xsd validation problems

Tags: xml, xsd

i know i have posted this question several times. but i'm now getting a new error, that i need help with. here is the error in which i am receiving.  "s4s-elt-invalid-content.1: The content of '#AnonType_orders' is invalid. Element 'element' is invalid, misplaced, or occurs too often."

here is my xsd file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:simpleType name="reach">
        <xs:restriction base = "xs:integer">
          <xs:enumeration value = "50" />
          <xs:enumeration value = "75" /> 
          <xs:enumeration value = "100" />
         </xs:restriction>
 </xs:simpleType>
<xs:simpleType name = "language">
    <xs:restriction base = "xs:string">
        <xs:enumeration value = "Spanish" />
        <xs:enumeration value = "Chinese" />
        <xs:enumeration value = "English" />
        <xs:enumeration value = "German" />
        <xs:enumeration value = "French" />
     </xs:restriction>
   </xs:simpleType>
<xs:simpleType name="caseColor">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:enumeration value="Lemonde" />
        <xs:enumeration value="Strawberry" />
        <xs:enumeration value="Lime" />
        <xs:enumeration value="Blueberry" />
    </xs:restriction> 
  </xs:simpleType>
<xs:simpleType name="numOfBat">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
        <xs:enumeration value="1" />
        <xs:enumeration value="2" />
        <xs:enumeration value="3" />
        <xs:enumeration value="4" />
    </xs:restriction> 
  </xs:simpleType>
<xs:simpleType name="numOfCam">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:pattern value="1|2" />
    </xs:restriction> 
  </xs:simpleType>
<xs:simpleType name="volt">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:enumeration value="110-120" />
        <xs:enumeration value="220-240" />
    </xs:restriction> 
  </xs:simpleType>
<xs:element name="orders">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:element name ="order" maxOccurs="unbounded"> 
<xs:complexType>
 <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="custName" type ="xs:string" />
                <xs:attribute name ="custID" />
<xs:element name="case" type="xs:caseColor" >
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="batteries" type="xs:numOfBat" default = 
"1"> 
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="recharger" type="xs:volt" /> 
<xs:element name="arm"> 
   <xs:element name ="reaches" minOccurs="2" maxOccurs="3" 
type="xs:reach" />
</xs:element>
<xs:element name ="camera" type="xs:numOfCam" /> 
<xs:element name = "speech" type="xs:language" />
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

here is my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<orders>
<order>
<custName custID="11223"> John Doe </custName>
<case> Strawberry </case>
<batteries> 2 </batteries>
<recharger> 110-120 V </recharger>
<arm>  
   <reach> 50 </reach>
   <reach> 100 </reach>
</arm>
<camera> 2 </camera>
<speech> Spanish </speech>
</order>
<order>
<custName custID="45392"> Jane Camp </custName>
<case> Lime </case>
<batteries> 4 </batteries>
<recharger> 220-240 V </recharger>
<arm> 3
   <reach> 75 </reach>
   <reach> 75 </reach>
   <reach> 100 </reach>
</arm>
<camera> 1 </camera>
<speech> Chinese </speech>
</order>
<order>
<custName custID="69482"> George Carlton </custName>
<case> Blueberry </case>
<batteries> 1 </batteries>
<recharger> 110-120 V </recharger>
<arm> 
   <reach> 75 </reach>
   <reach> 100 </reach>
</arm>
<camera> 2 </camera>
<speech> French </speech>
</order>
</orders>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `xsd` is badly formed, specifically your `orders` element.  You are also referencing the wrong namespace for your custom types.  I'll run down the issues that i see.

First: your `orders` node is defined as a `xs:complexType` and you have an `order` element as the child of `complexType`, but element is not a permitted child node.  You need to put `xs:sequence` or `xs:all` in between:

```
<xs:element name="orders">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name ="order" maxOccurs="unbounded">
         <!-- existing nodes -->
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Next: your `arm` element has 1 child element, but `xs:element` is not permitted in this context.  You need to define it as a `complexType` and then `sequence` or `all` again.

```
<xs:element name="arm">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name ="reaches" minOccurs="2" maxOccurs="3" type="reach" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Third: your `custId` attribute is not defined in the correct location.  `xs:attributes` have to be defined as a child node under the element in which they are defined as an attribute, however xs:simpleType cannot have an attribute node, so you need to instead define it as a complexType.  Here's a possible solution to your problem here:

```
<xs:element name="custName">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:simpleContent>
            <xs:extension base="xs:string">
               <xs:attribute name="custID" type="xs:int" use="required" />
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

And lastly: when you reference all of your custom types (`reach`, `numOfBat`, `volt`, etc), you are referencing them as part of the `xs:` namespace, however these types are not defined in the `xs:` namespace.  Since you don't define a targetNamespace for the XSD, your custom types become part of the default namespace.  You just need to remove the `xs:` from the type.

For example, you should be declaring them like: `type="reach"`, `type="numOfBat"`, `type="caseColor"`, etc

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what tool you are using for validation, but the messages it produces seem to be rather unhelpful. For information, here are the messages produced by Saxon:

```
Saxon-EE 9.5.0.1J from Saxonica
Java version 1.6.0_27
Using license serial number M008277
Loading schema document file:/Users/mike/Desktop/temp/test.xsd
Error at xs:element on line 48 column 49 of test.xsd:
  Element xs:element cannot appear here: expected one of {choice, sequence, assert,
  openContent, annotation, attributeGroup, anyAttribute, simpleContent, all, attribute,
  group, complexContent}
Error at xs:attribute on line 52 column 48 of test.xsd:
  Element <xs:attribute> is not allowed as a child of <xs:sequence>
Error at xs:element on line 61 column 19 of test.xsd:
  Element xs:element cannot appear here: expected one of {annotation, simpleType, key,
  complexType, keyref, unique, alternative}
Error at xs:element on line 61 column 19 of test.xsd:
  Element <xs:element> is not allowed as a child of <xs:element>
Schema processing failed: 4 errors were found while processing the schema
```

I hope you find these clearer. Essentially, the problem is that xs:element cannot appear as a child of xs:complexType: you probably need something like xs:sequence in between.

Comment: here is the site that i am using to validate my code.
http://corefiling.com/opensource/schemaValidate.html

Comment: i'm really not sure what i am doing wrong and how to fix the error. any suggestions?

Comment: @JohnTinio see my answer.  You have several issues that i see.